# Clear or disable mibs cache

Tags: pysnmp, mib

I have to debug a MIB file from a vendor and need to adapt lots of things to make it currently work with pysnmp. Therefore I would like to clear or disable the mibs cache ($HOME/.pysnmp/mibs) when initializing my script.

Is it possible to clear, empty or disable the mib cache programmatically?

This would make my workflow easier, especially later when porting to staging and production where the mibs are probably cached too.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to disable MIB compiler writing MIBs on the file system because pysnmp needs to read them back (SNMP engine and MIB compiler are quite loosely coupled and could be used stand-alone each).

You can control where exactly the MIB modules would be written though (e.g. `ObjectIdentity.addAsn1MibSource(destination='DIR')`).

Alternatively, a minor patch to pysnmp would let you force MIB compiler to re-build the cache on every invocation. Would that be helpful with your workflow?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the hint to make use of destination, this will help me for sure during roll-out.